# optimize query with minus oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization

Wanted to optimize a query with the minus that it takes too much time ... if they can give thanked help.

I have two tables A and B,

Table A: ID, value

Table B: ID

I want all of Table A records that are not in Table B. Showing the value.
For it was something like:

```
Select ID, value
FROM A
WHERE value> 70
MINUS
Select ID
FROM B;
```

Only this query is taking too long ... any tips how best this simple query?

Thank you for attention

Comment: When your query takes too long: https://community.oracle.com/message/1814597

Comment: In response to your answer that you deleted:
 `CREATE INDEX tablea_id ON a (id);`
`CREATE INDEX tablea_value ON a (value(10));`
`CREATE INDEX tableb_value ON b (id);`

As seen from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/create-index.html

Comment: the problem is that supposedly can not create index on the table .... escapes my control...

Comment: Hi, please see my updated answer. You can dramatically improve the performance of a query with Indexes. There is nothing wrong with your query nor MINUS nor NOT EXISTS, there is nothing magic going on. The reason it takes so long is because you're doing it all without indexing. I hope this helps.

If you cannot create the indexes then you are stuck with poor performance. Whoever is in charge of the database. Tell them that they need to pull their head out of their backside and index the table!

Comment: Another thought I just has is you can produce a materialised view. A materialised view loads the data into memory at intervals you specify if I recall, once a day or once an hour. So when you query that view it should be instant. You could try creating the materialised view of each of the tables if you wish, that might help with performance. It's been around 6 months since I worked with Oracle so I'm not too sure on specifics.

Answer (score 4):

Are ID and Value indexed?

The performance of Minus and Not Exists depend:

> It really depends on a bunch of factors.
>
> A MINUS will do a full table scan on both tables unless there is some
>   criteria in the where clause of both queries that allows an index
>   range scan. A MINUS also requires that both queries have the same
>   number of columns, and that each column has the same data type as the
>   corresponding column in the other query (or one convertible to the
>   same type). A MINUS will return all rows from the first query where
>   there is not an exact match column for column with the second query. A
>   MINUS also requires an implicit sort of both queries
>
> NOT EXISTS will read the sub-query once for each row in the outer
>   query. If the correlation field (you are running a correlated
>   sub-query?) is an indexed field, then only an index scan is done.
>
> The choice of which construct to use depends on the type of data you
>   want to return, and also the relative sizes of the two tables/queries.
>   If the outer table is small relative to the inner one, and the inner
>   table is indexed (preferrable a unique index but not required) on the
>   correlation field, then NOT EXISTS will probably be faster since the
>   index lookup will be pretty fast, and only executed a relatively few
>   times. If both tables a roughly the same size, then MINUS might be
>   faster, particularly if you can live with only seeing fields that you
>   are comparing on.

[Minus operator versus 'not exists' for faster SQL query - Oracle Community Forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/19816)

You could use `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Value
    From a 
    where a.value > 70
    and not exists(
        Select b.ID
        From B
        Where b.ID = a.ID)
```

EDIT: I've produced some dummy data and two datasets for testing to prove the performance increases of indexing. Note: I did this in MySQL since I don't have Oracle on my Macbook.

**Table A** has 2600 records with 2 columns: ID, val. 
ID is an autoincrement integer
Val varchar(255)

**Table b** has one column, but more records than Table A. Autoincrement (in gaps of 3)

You can reproduce this if you wish: [Pastebin - SQL Dummy Data](http://pastebin.com/k2r7kvFq)

Here is the query I will be using:

```
select a.id, a.val from tablea a
where length(a.val) > 3
and not exists(
    select b.id from tableb b where b.id = a.id
);
```

Without Indexes, the runtime is **986ms** with 1685 rows.

Now we add the indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablea` ADD INDEX `id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tableb` ADD INDEX `id` (`id`);
```

With Indexes, the runtime is **14ms** with 1685 rows. That's **1.42%** the time it took without indexes!

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The fields are not indexed. And I think the table B is greater than A. but have the clause where where I notice a big difference in speed. The problem is even go check the entire table B. I want the value (number) of all that are in table A but not in Table B. And for the two tables alloys have an ID (number).
Honestly can not see great improvements to make .. I think in this case I'm not much to gain from not exists ...
It is possible to use pl / sql in this query. It seems good option to use pl / sql loading the data into memory?